# Formating json object into Array of dictionary in swift

Tags: nsjsonserialization

```
   let todoEndpoint: String ="http://localhost:16789/api/product"
    guard let url = NSURL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        do{
            self.users = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? Array}
        catch{
            print("Error parsing")
        }



        }
    task.resume()
```

this is my Output my API
       [{"ProductId":2,"Category":"Laptop","Brand":"Apple","ModelName":"MacBook Pro","SerialNumber":"Test1","DatePurchased":"2016-08-12T00:00:00","EmployeeName":"Vismita Shetty","DateAssigned":"2017-01-17T00:00:00"},{"ProductId":4,"Category":"Keyboard","Brand":"Logitech","ModelName":"K200","SerialNumber":"TestKeyboard1","DatePurchased":"2017-01-23T03:02:13.247","EmployeeName":"Vismita Shetty","DateAssigned":"2017-01-17T00:00:00"},{"ProductId":5,"Category":"Keyboard","Brand":"Logitech","ModelName":"K200","SerialNumber":"testkeyboard2","DatePurchased":"2017-01-23T03:03:26.07","EmployeeName":"Suraj Pangam","DateAssigned":"2017-01-17T00:00:00"}]

What I currently trying to do convert user into different variable which will be of type Array of dictionaries in swift. So that Each object can be accessed by key. I want to make it generic so that even some properties got changed it won't matter as it won't be accessed by providing property name. Like (users[indexPath.row] as? [String: AnyObject])?["EmployeeName"] as! String!.

Instead if i make it to dictionary i will be easily do it by running for (key,value) loop for array of dictionary.